# Add another key/value pair to all objects inside a jsonb array in POSTGRES

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table, let's call it myTable with the following structure

```
ID   | data
____________
uuid | jsonb
```

The data in the jsonb field is an array structured in the following way:

```
[
  {
    "valueA": "500",
    "valueB": "ABC",
  },
  {
    "valueA": "300",
    "valueB": "CDE",
  }
]
```

What I want to do is transform that data by adding a valueC and set it to valueA, for all the objects inside the 'data' jsonb array.

This is the result I want:

```
[
  {
    "valueA": "500",
    "valueB": "ABC",
    "valueC": "500",
  },
  {
    "valueA": "300",
    "valueB": "CDE",
    "valueC": "300",
  }
]
```

I tried doing it with the following query:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET data = d.json_array
FROM (
    SELECT
        jsonb_agg(
                 jsonb_set(elems, '{valueC}', elems->'valueA')
        ) as json_array
    FROM
        myTable,
        jsonb_array_elements(data) elems
) d;
```

This worked for some on the entries in myTable, but for some it went crazy and created 300+ additional entries, along with the ones I previosly had.

What am I missing in my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those `FROM` statements are unnecessary. You shouldn't need one on the `UPDATE` clause at all - your problem is that the subquery does a `FROM myTable` and then basically self-joins (by cartesian product) this subquery result against the whole `myTable`. The last (or really, any) `UPDATE` to each row wins, depending on the join order, making your result unpredictable.

I'd move the subquery in the `SET` clause where it only refers to the `data` of the row that is being updated:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET data = (
    SELECT jsonb_agg(
        jsonb_set(elems, '{valueC}', elems->'valueA')
    )
    FROM jsonb_array_elements(data) elems
);
```

Alternatively, you would need to add a JOIN condition between the updated table and the `FROM` result:

```
UPDATE myTable u
SET data = d.json_array
FROM (
    SELECT
        id,
        jsonb_agg(
                 jsonb_set(elems, '{valueC}', elems->'valueA')
        ) as json_array
    FROM
        myTable,
        jsonb_array_elements(data) elems
    GROUP BY
        id
) d
WHERE
    u.id = d.id;
```

Comment: Thank you, both for the correct query and the explanation why mine was acting weird, tested the first one and it works great